# CDI Producermethod ignored

Tags: java, jboss, cdi, wildfly, jboss-weld

I am totally at a loss! I have this Class:

```
package com.company.resources
import com.company.transport.Repository; //an interface for an EJB
import com.company.transport.Expression; //a simple DTO, returned by the Interface

public class ResourceProducer
{

    //@EJB(lookup="foo") Repository repo;

    @Produces @Named("archive")
    public String getArchiveString() {
        return "archive";
    }

    @Produces @Named("repository")
    public Repository getRemoteRepository(){
        //return repo;
        return new Repository(){
            @Override
            public Expression getExpression(String s, Long aLong) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And, simply put the String one works, the other one is ignored by the container (Wildfly 9 / Weld).

At the begining I wanted to inject an EJB and `getRemoteRepository` was not annotated as @Named, as i only know supply one Producer for the interface `Repository`. Getting the errors, i changed them to be the same, to limit the scope for the error, even in the Injection Points:

```
package com.company.resources
public Class ExpressionProxy {
     @Inject @Named("archive") String target;
     @Inject @Named("repository") Repositroy repo;
}
```

I get:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Repository with qualifiers @Default
     at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject com.company.resources.ExpressionProxy
```

**I do not get this Exception for The String!**

Also, if i annotate `ResourceProducer` with `@ApplicationScoped` - making it a Bean - I expect getting ambigous bindings - as my Producer now is found via the `@Produces` Annotation itself and is present in a Managed Bean.

I also only get ambigous binding Exceptions for the String, never for `Repository`

I moved both classes to one .war and to the same package - it simply wont work with `Repository`.

I did CDI injection via Interfaces before - what is the Problem here?

EDIT: to give full disclosure:

I deploy this in an ear, as a library:

```
app.ear/
    -jaxrs.war # contains rest interface, irrelevant for this bug
    -lib/
        -beans.jar #contains the Producer and ExpressionProxy 
        -RepositoryInterface.jar # containts Repository and Expression
```

i tried every permutation of the 3 archives involved.

- the mentioned
- `beans` and `interfaces` as library in the .war
- `beans` as additional deployment
- `beans` as additional deployment AND in ear/lib

The beans in /lib obviously get scanned by weld, as the String does not make any problems.

Comment: Can you clarify this bit? "Also, if i annotate ResourceProducer with `@ApplicationScoped` - making it a Bean - I expect getting ambigous bindings - as my Producer now is found via the `@Produces` Annotation itself and is present in a Managed Bean. " -- To me, adding `@ApplicationScoped` there should *not* cause an exception for ambiguous binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cited from the Weld documentation [2.2.3](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#_producer_methods)

> A producer method must be a non-abstract method of a **managed bean** class or **session bean** class. A producer method may be either static or non-static. If the bean is a session bean, the producer method must be either a business method of the EJB or a static method of the bean class.

So you could annotate your `ResourceProducer` with `@ApplicationScoped`.

*Note*: Using any modern IDE should tell you, that you are missing the required dependencies on compile. This saves you the time to deploy your application.